# How to create a funnel visual/bar chart in Tableau by creating a calculated field using an existing column in the data source?

Tags: sql, data-visualization, bar-chart, tableau-api, calculated-field

In my data source, there's a column called 'Pool'

Within that column, there are about 3 values:

```
|  Pool  |
|   C    |
|   B    |
|   C    |
|   A    |
```

So as you can see, there are 3 distinct values, A, B, C. I want to create a funnel, or essentially a bar chart that will calculate each and count them in the whole column for each of those three values. However, I know I can't just place the column itself in the sheet since I also want to have a fourth bar that counts all the values as a "All" category.

So eventually having a visual that states (but this is in tabular form to help illustrate what I mean)

```
All | 20
A   | 10
B   | 5
C   | 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find an indicative answer in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9533a663f67adcf8c378af09662173d0)

You could use `UNION` between two results one to bring the `COUNT` for each of your values and one `COUNT` for all your samples.

```
(SELECT Pool, COUNT(Pool) AS your_count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Pool)
UNION
(SELECT 'ALL', COUNT(*) AS your_count
FROM your_table)
ORDER BY your_count DESC
```